# UISplitViewController with tableView as detailView bug

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I make application with UISplitViewController. Above it i have contaner controller in which i override:

```
let tc = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .regular)
self.setOverrideTraitCollection(tc, forChildViewController: svc)
```

To get same functionality for iPhones and iPads.

```
svc.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.primaryHidden
svc.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.8
svc.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 500
```

When i activate PrimaryViewController SplitViewController preferredDisplayMode is becoming allVisible and the detailView(tableView) swipes right  but whith bug as on screens

[primaryViewBug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLWOA.png)

left side labels  and right side label are driven on each other
Will be thankful for any ideas on how to correct this bug

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. In my tableViewCell i have rightLabel contraint to the rightAnchor of cell. I make this constaint priority to low and add another constranint to the leftAcnchor of cell with required priority.

```
let rightAnch = rigthtLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -8)
    rightAnch.priority = .defaultLow
    rightAnch.isActive = true
let leftAnch = rigthtLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: leftAnchor, constant: 200)
    leftAnch.priority = .required
    leftAnch.isActive = true
```